# Sending complex objects as formData with blueimp fileuploader

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, blueimp

I'm trying to send an array of objects (`Tags`) to a .NET controller method using blueimp fileuploader. The problem is my array of objects won't map to my ViewModel property in the controller. All other "simple" property types are mapped.

To submit the file and it's associated formData I do the following:

```
data.formData = self.model.attributes;
data.submit();
```

Inspecting `data.formData` before submission, my data seems to be correctly formatted:

```
data.formData = 
{
  "Id": 75,
  "ContractValue": null,
  "Name": "New doc w\/ tags",
  "FileName": "icon-watched.png",
  "StartDate": "",
  "EndDate": "",
  "LastModifiedDate": "07 Mar 2014 - 16:21",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "TagId": 1,
      "Name": "Legal",
      "Tagger": ""
    },
    {
      "TagId": 2,
      "Name": "Approved",
      "Tagger": ""
    }
  ],
  "Reminders": [],
  "Suppliers": [],
  "DocumentType": "documents",
  "Errors": [],
  "IsValid": true,
  "Type": "image\/png",
  "TruncatedFileName": "icon-watched.png",
  "FileSize": 311
}
```

The `Tags` array appears to be formatted correctly but are registered as an empty list of Tags when the request hits the controller method. Am I missing something here or do I need to format the formData differently for complex objects?